# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. Download Html Code from Url

Tags: c#, httprequest

I use this code to download string html from url:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(currentUrl);
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
httpWebRequest.Timeout = 3600000;
httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv: 30.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 30.0";
HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
currenturlContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

---

I run a loop to get html from many urls of one website. I think the problem is website security. It can read html just the first time and then error happy.

The error is:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Comment: Can you show the code in the context of the loop which causes the error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Here is my loop
  while (currentPage <= toPage)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            lbCurrentPage.Text = currentPage.ToString();
                            currentUrl = createUrlUser(keyword, currentPage);
                            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

```
                        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(currentUrl);
                        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                        httpWebRequest.Timeout = 3600000;
                        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv: 30.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 30.0";
                        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
                        currenturlContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to close the streamReader once it is used: `streamReader.Close();`

See this link:

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-

> ... the problem always turns out to be that the developer called the `GetResponseStream()` method but failed to subsequently call `Close()` on the resulting object. The consequence is that .NET keeps the object alive indefinitely, which causes subsequent requests to eventually block on the default connections-per-host limit